# how to handle dynamic objects\controls with OpKey Personal edition

Tags: selenium, frameworks, automation

Any idea how to handle dynamic objects and controls from within OpKey Personal. We are using OpKey an automation framework over selenium since past one year but got into a problem lately.

My situation. a control in my web portal is displayed dynamically bsed on certain input parameters i choose. Using regular expression in OpKey object repository is not working.
Any idea how can i handle this situation

Comment: We found a solution that i am posing. OpKey allows you to create your custom keyword. I created a small custom keyword that takes the Object and converts it into regular expression